# Date Time Picker после выбора даты не переходит на выбор выбор времени(часов)

Tags: php, yii2, дата, время, datetimepicker

Мне нужно чтоб при выборе даты после указывались часы, но у меня на выборе даты все заканчивается.
https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker
Делал все как тут описанно, прошу помощи любой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтоб еще время выходило как тут[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'published_at')->widget(
   DateTimePicker::className(),[
     'language' => \Yii::$app->language,
     'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
     'size' => 'md',
      'pluginOptions' => [
        'minView' => 1, //<--- 1 запретить ввод минут, 0 разрешить ввод минут
        'immediateUpdates' => true,
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii',
       ],
    ], ['autocomplete' => 'off']
)->label();
?>
```